# TeXstudio's auto completion is completely not working on Fedora 20

Tags: texstudio, linux, auto-completion

I am a novice to the TeX community, and I am running Fedora 20 x64 on my workstation, with kernel version 3.17.

I installed TeXlive and TeXstudio via `yum`, and compilation seems to be working fine for some simple `tex` scripts I have attempted to create.

However, when I type in some thing such as `\in` (I wanted to have `\int`), no list of possible completion choices appear, even with the command `\usepackage{amsmath}` included in the preamble.

The auto completion function works fine on the Windows & Mac distros which I also use occasionally.

I have also selected the `amsmath.cwl` in the settings dialogue window, but nothing changed.

Please somebody help me out!

Answer (score 1):

See the image below. Check if you are selecting the correct options for auto completion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have selected the correct options as shown in the image, sadly, I am not seeing the pull-down box which would include the possible completions...The autocompletion for texmaker on the linux system is also malfunctioning... For texmaker, I can see the pull-down box, but it does not update dynamically as I type in more characters.

Comment: @user202531, sorry, I'm not following you. Did you install TeXstudio or TeXmaker? They are almost equal. Well, note on the image that the option *Show Advanced Options* is selected.

Comment: I first installed TeXstudio, and I found out that auto completion does not work. Then I used yum to install TeXmaker. I did note that the option Show Advanced Options is selected in the screenshot you kindly provided, which I didn't notice previously. I believe I have virtually cloned your options onto mine.

Comment: The ironic thing is, without any modifications to the settings panel, TeXstudio on my mac is functioning perfectly...

Comment: So I suggest you to download the latest version of TeXstudio from the official website.

Comment: TeX stuffs from repository usually does not work well.

Comment: I'm using TeXstudio 2.8.6